# cobra.mit.request.QueryError: Unable to process the query, result dataset is too big

Tags: python-2.7, sdk, cisco, apic, cobra

I try to run a python cobra sdk script to do a query in cisco aci apic database for class l1PhysIf to obtain a port inventory, code seems to be ok, but when I execute code I get error:

cobra.mit.request.QueryError: Unable to process the query, result dataset is too big

in my code I use a for loop for append query's obtained data to a empty list

my fabric has about 6900 ports so query results can be big, how can handle the code for obtain the data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use paging / pagination to reduce the size of query results

Comment: description of how pagination works can be found at https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/aci/apic/sw/2-x/rest_cfg/2_1_x/b_Cisco_APIC_REST_API_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_APIC_REST_API_Configuration_Guide_chapter_01.html